# Is there a special way to list Commerce Products?

Tags: views, commerce

- Drupal core 8.2.6
- Drupal Commerce 8.x-2.0-beta5
- Bootstrap 8.x-3.2

I tried making a View that renders Products in view mode (Grid of Products in Default view), but when I try to add a product to cart - if the product has no variations - often times a wrong product that has no variations gets added. If the product that I try to add has variations I get a php error: InvalidArgumentException: Unknown attribute field name "attribute_period". in Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariation->getAttributeValueId() (line 260 of drupal/modules/commerce/modules/product/src/Entity/ProductVariation.php).

Other attributes pop up there as well if I add a different product to cart.

It seems like it still tries to add a different product but provides the right variation name, which the different product does not have, so it errors.

If I view just the product on its own - works just fine. So for now I have the view show a table of products with "View" link, but I'd really like to be able to add products to cart right from the view. Any ideas for how to make that happen? I can't seem to find any tickets about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we have this captured in an issue. The main issue was https://www.drupal.org/node/2831895 and is now in https://www.drupal.org/node/2827721.

Part of our blocker has been getting tests for this. We need to build a test for the use case then work towards a resolution.

There is a pull request in progress at https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce/pull/582. I have not reviewed this and not sure how close it is to a final solution.

The issue is unique form IDs.